# epplus line graph change smooth line VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, epplus, linegraph

I am using epplus to create a line graph which by default is a smooth line. I want to switch the smooth line off so that it is a straight line from point to point. I am using VB but cannot find the property that I need to change.

```
Private Sub FillPostChart(objWorksheetChartPost As ExcelWorksheet, iRow2013 As Integer, iRowEnd As Integer, sChartTitle As String)
    Dim chtPost = objWorksheetChartPost.Drawings.AddChart("PostLineChart", 65)

    chtPost.Series.Add(ExcelRange.GetFullAddress("Data", "B" & iRow2013.ToString & ":B" & iRowEnd.ToString), ExcelRange.GetFullAddress("Data", "A" & iRow2013.ToString & ":A" & iRowEnd.ToString)).Header = "a"
    chtPost.Series.Add(ExcelRange.GetFullAddress("Data", "D" & iRow2013.ToString & ":D" & iRowEnd.ToString), ExcelRange.GetFullAddress("Data", "A" & iRow2013.ToString & ":A" & iRowEnd.ToString)).Header = "b"
    chtPost.Series.Add(ExcelRange.GetFullAddress("Data", "G" & iRow2013.ToString & ":G" & iRowEnd.ToString), ExcelRange.GetFullAddress("Data", "A" & iRow2013.ToString & ":A" & iRowEnd.ToString)).Header = "c"

    chtPost.Title.Text = sChartTitle
    chtPost.SetSize(1200, 800)
    chtPost.DisplayBlanksAs = Chart.eDisplayBlanksAs.Gap
End Sub
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out. Download the latest version as this was a bug in EPPlus. Also I should have declared chtpost as ExcelLineChart and imported Imports OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.Chart

Hope this helps someone else.

Thanks,